# write text file without deleting older saves with python

Tags: python

I'm somewhat new to python and I want to create a new txt file **without replacing** the old file

I try this to create a new file:

```
def savebill():

    lineadd=" -------------------------------------------\n" 
    print (lineadd)
    bill=open('bill.txt','w')
    bill.write(lineadd)
    bill.close()
```

When I Want to save **a new** bill the old file  it will be replaced,I need to **keep a copy of the old saves**.

Comment: Note if you use a `with` statement, you don't need the `f.close()`: `with open('bill.txt', 'w') as bill: bill.write(lineadd)`

Comment: See the documenation for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) under "*mode*".

Comment: @wjandrea I try to use 'b' for binary mode, but it save a new bill in the same file, i want to create new file

Comment: Binary mode?? I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Please make a [mcve] of the current problem, [edit] it into the question, and give more details about the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Change the 'w' to 'a+':

```
bill=open('bill.txt','a+')
```

`open` is built-in function that open file and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is raised.

The first parameter is the file name that you want to open and the second parameter is the mode (there are more parameters).

There is 7 options for the mode:

> 'r' - open for reading (default)
>
> 'w' - open for writing, truncating the file first
>
> 'x' - open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
>
> 'a' - open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
>
> 'b' - binary mode
>
> 't' - text mode (default)
>
> '+' - open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)

You can combine with some parameters, for example: `'r+b'` opens the file without truncation.

For more information, read the docs file:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Could you please [edit] and add a brief explanation of why this works? A link to the documentation on [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) would help too.

Comment: ‘a’ : indicate that the output of the program will be append to the previous output of the file, I want to create a new txt file with the same name without replacing the old file, or rename the new file automatically

Answer (score 0):

```py
import fnmatch
import os

def savebill():
    lineadd=" -------------------------------------------\n" 
    print (lineadd)
    # set a file target and check if it exists 
    files = fnmatch.filter((f for f in os.listdir('.')), 'bill*.txt') #target filename 
    
    file = len(files) # how many the files with the name are
    file + 1 # if you had "bill20.txt", adding 1 makes your new file to  be "bill21.txt"... etc
    bill = open('bill%s.txt'% file)
    bill.write('text')
    bill.close()
    # Can also be used in saving any file
```

Comment: Thanks To HK boy for the edit,  I was having a hard time with that. Thanks